# Firebase auth takes extremely long on Android build

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I've ran into a problem of ridiculously long wait times for Firebase auth to finish. This is only observed on the Android build, in the Editor the wait times are what I would expect.

This is the code I use for the sign in:

```
    public static void SignIn(string email, string password, Action callback)
    {
        _auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
            .ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => HandleSignIn(task, callback));
        Debug.Log("Log in request sent, waiting for finish");
    }

    private static void HandleSignIn(Task<FirebaseUser> task, Action callback)
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Sign in was canceled");
            return;
        }

        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Error during sign in: {task.Exception}");
            return;
        }


        var signedInUser = task.Result;
        GetUserData(signedInUser.UserId, callback);

        Debug.Log($"User signed in successfully. Name: {signedInUser.DisplayName}, ID: {signedInUser.UserId}");
    }

    public static void GetUserData(string userId, Action callback)
    {
        var documentReference = _firestore.Collection(USERS_COLLECTION).Document(userId);

        documentReference.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => HandleUserData(task, callback));
    }

    private static void HandleUserData(Task<DocumentSnapshot> task, Action callback)
    {
        var snapshot = task.Result;

        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            _user = snapshot.ConvertTo<User>();
            _user.Id = snapshot.Id;

            Debug.Log("User data retrieved");

            callback?.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"User with user ID {snapshot.Id} does not exist");
        }
    }
```

It takes about 4-5 minutes to get to this piece of Debug.Log:

```
Debug.Log($"User signed in successfully. Name: {newUser.DisplayName}, ID: {newUser.UserId}");
```

I haven't been able to get further than that, I've waited like 10 minutes beyond that point and got no further logs.

Has anyone ever ran into such an issue?

This is the only related thread I could find online but there is no resolution posted:
https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/anRL39_-Tr4

There are no errors or exceptions being thrown, it seems that it just takes very long for the tasks to finish.

**EDIT:**

The problem is not present on iOS builds. It seems to only affect Android builds.